# Attribute to make Action not available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to retain the code of some unused methods in my controllers in case I need them again in future.

To prevent accidental access, I thought of using the following attribute to mark all such methods:

```
[Authorize(Roles="This Role will never be assigned.")]
```

This works, but only after first getting the user to log in.  Is there a more elegant way?

Comment: ^^ Exactly. Why have lingering code if you have no use for it in your current build? This way, it won't even be compiled, and you can still use it at a later date.

Comment: Delete it. That is what source control is for. Commented out code is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use The `NonActionAttribute`. It allows you to mark public methods in a controller as not being available for external requests.

[Here's more information.](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2011/04/09/asp-net-mvc-using-nonactionattribute-to-restrict-access-to-public-methods-of-controller.aspx)

Comment: Returns a 404. Perfect!